# Drone.io build failed exit code 1

Tags: go, continuous-integration, drone.io

Attached is a snippet of my drone (v0.4) build log when I trigger a build by pushing my project to master. Cant figure out why the build is failing. Am I missing something [here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQxqW.png)

Comment: You can't build go-sqlite3 without cgo.